# QDockWidget causes qt to crash

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qdockwidget

I Have the version of Qt that is built into ubuntu 11.10.  And am trying to use a `QDockWidget` that cannot actually dock (basically, I just want a window that floats.  I don't want to just make the view be a top level view because then I would have the OS window bar up there, which I don't want, and if I were to hide it, then the window won't be movable).

So, I basically make a new Qt Gui project, and don't change any of the files, except for the `mainwindow.cpp` file, which I change to:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDockWidget>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QDockWidget *dockWidget = new QDockWidget(this);
    // Without window management and attached to mainwindow (central widget)
    dockWidget->setFloating( true );
    // resize by frame only - not positional moveable
    dockWidget->setFeatures( QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable );
    // never dock in mainwindow
    dockWidget->setAllowedAreas( Qt::NoDockWidgetArea );
    // title
    dockWidget->setWindowTitle( "Dock Widget" );
    // add contents. etc etc....
    dockWidget->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

The problem is that when I go to move the widget, the whole program crashes.  I want to know if I am doing something very wrong, or if there is just a bug in qt.

Comment: I get the same result and I can't find any documentation that would indicate why it shouldn't work. It may be a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You made the widget floating but not floatable.

```
dockWidget->setFeatures( QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable | 
    QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable );
```

And you can also have a movable frameless window, by handling the mouse dragging yourself through `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`.

---

#### How to hide the now useless float button

Based on `QDockWidget` source code, the "float button" is not shown if there is a title bar widget:

```
 dockWidget->setTitleBarWidget(new QLabel("Dock Widget", dockWidget));
```

Or since it has a name (which isn't documented), you can hide it explicitly:

```
 QAbstractButton * floatButton = 
   dockWidget->findChild<QAbstractButton*>("qt_dockwidget_floatbutton");
 if(floatButton) 
     floatButton->hide();
```

Comment: +1 That did indeed prevent the crash on my end, although I would still consider the crash to be a bug.

Comment: This works, but is there any way to get rid of that dock button on the top left?  As there is no where for it to dock it doesn't do anything and looks ugly.  Thank you.